# I can not apply rig to my mesh

Tags: mesh, armature, parent, rigify

I'm a beginner in blender and I can't solve this problem. I can't connect my rig to the mesh no matter what I do.I am  hoping  for your help and I would be very grateful for it.

[image]

Comment: If Lukas' answer doesn't work please share your file

Answer (score 0):

**Update** (after receiving file):

Your mesh is broken. It is neither symmetrical, nor is the transformation applied, nor only-quads and has lots of duplicated vertices. So

1. Fix your mesh
2. Continue as described before:

Select your Object/Mesh, <kbd>Shift</kbd>-select your armature, then press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on windows) and choose one of the options (since you have a human character, "With Automatic Weights" seems to be a good option).

Comment: Thank you for answering to my question. I already did that and it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: your screenshot shows your armature in pose mode. you need to do that in object mode

Comment: I did as you told me and it won't work again, I'm afraid I made a mistake sculpting the model. This is how it looks now.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lUzmDd0QIdfVxbL_nkSw8Kj9NxVoWiav/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: can you upload your file on https://blend-exchange.com/?

Comment: It says that the file is too big, but here is the link to my drive
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wO2UdJqrPru5JX1kNk2srDQtp6nf3HjA/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: i updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!!